# How do you add a runtime string parameter into a dependency resolution chain?

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject, autofac

How could I setup my chosen DI for this kind of setup:

```
public abstract class BaseRepo
{
     public BaseRepo(string token)
     {
     }
}

public RepoA : BaseRepo, IRepoA
{
     // implementation of interface here    
}

public ViewModelA
{
     IRepoA _repo;
     public ViewModelA(IRepoA repo)
     {
       this._repo = repo;
     }

     public DoMethod()
     {
        this._repo.DoSomeStuff();
     }
}
```

In real scenario, the token parameter on the base class is resolved after the user has been logged in. I was thinking of just configuring the interfaces for DI after the login but I'm not sure if that a right thing do.

I looked at some Factories but I can't make it to work.

My choice of DI probably goes to AutoFac/Ninject and the project is Xamarin mobile app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In real scenario, the token parameter on the base class is resolved
>   after the user has been logged in.

This means that the token parameter is *runtime data*. Prevent injecting runtime data into your components. Your components should be stateless. Instead, runtime data should be passed on through method calls through the previously constructed object graph of components. Failing to do so, will make it much more complicated to configure and verify your object graphs.

There are typically to ways of passing runtime data. Either you pass it on through method calls from method to method through the object graph, or your components call a method that returns that correct value. This token seems like it is contextual information and that would typically mean you choose the latter option:

```
public interface ITokenProvider {
    string GetCurrentToken();
}

// Don't use base classes: base classes are a design smell!
public RepoA : IRepoA
{
     private readonly ITokenProvider tokenProvider;
     public RepoA(ITokenProvider tokenProvider) {
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
     }

     // IRepoA methods
     public A GetById(Guid id) {
         // Get token at runtime
         string token = this.tokenProvider.GetCurrentToken();

         // Use token here.
     }
}
```

In your [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/), you will have to create an implementation for this `ITokenProvider`. How this implementation looks is highly dependent on how you wish to store this token, but here's a possible implementation:

```
public sealed class AspNetSessionTokenProvider : ITokenProvider {
    public string GetCurrentToken() {
        return (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["token"];
    }
}
```

Comment: I have since [added an FAQ on this topic to the Autofac documentation site](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq/injecting-global-parameters.html).