# Setting initial values for class when using Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, wpf, constructor, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm using unity for dependency injection in my application.  Per best practices, only the root of my application knows anything about the `UnityContainer`, and everything else resolves down the chain.

For example my `WorksheetViewModel` is:

```
public WorksheetViewModel(CollateralEditViewModel collateralEditViewModel,
                          AddCollateralToWorksheetViewModel addCollateralToWorksheetViewModel,
                          CollateralWorksheetsViewModel collateralWorksheetsViewModel,
                          Publisher<RequestEventArgs> freaPublisher,
                          IWorksheetLogic worksheetLogic)
```

This works well.  However, when I am ready to show my worksheet (from another view, not the application root), I need to send it its worksheetID so it can initialize itself.

Is there a way to do this in the constructor?  It doesn't seem possible as the `WorksheetViewModel` has already been constructed.  Is the common pattern here just to use another method as a pseudo-constructor? I.E.

```
public void InitializeWorksheetWithID(int ID)
```

Or is there a better approach than this with DI?

**UPDATE**

Maybe I need more information.  Imagine the guy who opens the `WorksheetViewModel` to look like:

```
public class MyOtherViewModel
{
    private WorksheetViewModel _worksheetViewModel;

    public MyOtherViewModel(WorksheetViewModel worksheetViewModel)
    {
         _worksheetViewModel = worksheetViewModel;
    }

    public void SomeActionPerformedByUser(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
    {
         var worksheetID = e.ID;
         _worksheetViewModel.InitializeWorksheetWithID(worksheetID);

         DoStuffToDisplayView(_worksheetViewModel);
    }
}
```

This seems like it would be a very common scenario in the Dependency Injection Pattern.  I'm concerned why I can't find much on the subject.

Comment: how do you pass the worksheetID when initializing a worksheet within the "root" of your application?

Comment: if i had a need to initialize a worksheet from my root, I could tack on an `int ID` parameter and inject it with Unity.  Currently, I don't ever initialize a worksheet from my root, only from other views.  The root is basically a search dashboard.  I have a decent amount of views that are instantiated in this fashion

Comment: why not doing the same with one of your views?

Comment: This can be several views in.  At the time that unity resolves the class,  I don't know what ID the worksheet will need yet.  Unless I'm missing what you're getting at.  If I am, an example would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest option is to create a setter like you have mentioned.
There are many approaches, but this is the simplest.
You have chosen to use Unity like a DI container, therefore your constructors function as dependency wiring code.
The `ID` is not a dependency.

Based on your comment...

> At the time that unity resolves the class, I don't know what ID the worksheet will need yet.

...I think it is safe to assume that a valid worksheet may exist without an ID, therefore ID is not a construction-time concern.

If I misinterpreted your comment, then you might want to consider creating this:

```
struct WorksheetId
{
    int Id;
}
```

And adding `WorksheetId` as a dependency in your constructor.

Comment: thanks @dss539.  I added a bit of information if that helps make my case more clear.

Comment: @Jonesopolis Your update makes it very clear to me that the object may exist without having an ID. I think your first instinct was correct, and you just need a method to set the ID.

Comment: @dss539 is correct. The worksheetId is runtime data and shouldn't be mixed with constructor injection. The mentioned `WorksteetId` struct is known as a provider. You're mentioned solution in the update of the question is known as interface injectoin or method injection. IMO this kind of data should just flow through the system through method calls. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32033788/3294832) answer

Comment: thanks @Ric.Net for the link.  That guy phrased his question much better than I did.  I feel much more comfortable with this approach.  Thanks @dss539!